# JSON.parse incorrectly transforming string to char

Tags: node.js, parsing, unicode

I have a string like this:

```
 const str =  { "_id": "x", "test": "rxh", "access_data": { "account" : "1", "password" : "r\u0026", "name" : "eu" } }
```

And i am using JSON.Parse to parse this string.
The problem is that the parse understant the part "\u0026" of my password as a unicode, and transforms it to "&"

if I try JSON.Parse(str)
the return is:

```
{
  _id: 'x',
  institution_id: 'rxh',
  access_data: { account: '1', password: 'r&', name: 'eu' }
}
```

How can I avoid this transformation?

Answer (score 1):

To encode a literal back slash, use two backslashes (`\\`)

```
JSON.parse(String.raw`"r\\u0026"`) === String.raw`r\u0026`
```

If you're using *JSON.stringify* where you produce the JSON string, it should take care of this for you:

```
let dataBundle = { password: String.raw`r\u0026` };
console.log(JSON.stringify(dataBundle));
```

Also, please be very careful about passing passwords in plain text.  I don't know your situation, but it's best to leave account sign-in to widgets that do that for you.  They often salt passwords before sending them over the network.

Comment: ok .. but in this case i am matching the whole password.. but i can have different passwords with \.. I am trying to match only the "\" and replace but it isnt working

Comment: @gara, The question contains no matching code, so I can't help you debug it.